# Import multiple named exports of module into a single object

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

Suppose I have:

**animals.js**

```
import cat from './cat';
import dog from './dog';
import emu from './emu';
import pig from './pig';
import cow from './cow';

export { cat, dog, emu, pig, cow };
```

In a module that uses `animals.js`, how can I import only a couple of needed ones into a keyed object? I'd like to be able to do something like:

**my-module.js**

```
import { cat, dog } as housePets from './animals';

// housePets == { cat: theCatModule, dog: theDogModule }
```

But according to my IDE, this syntax is not correct.

Is there a way to do this? Or is the best way to simply import all of them individually, then construct my own objects afterward?

Comment: either of the two ways are correct. But its better to import only those modules which is used in the file.

Comment: @VikashSingh You say either of the two ways are correct, but the example I provided in my question is not proper syntax according to my IDE, so it does not work. Are you aware of a syntax during the import that allows me to do what I'm asking?

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting in your IDE?

Comment: Several errors because it's not legal JS syntax. Specifically, in Webstorm, I get `Expression statement is not assignment or call`. The spaces before and after `from` are red squigglied: `Expecting newline or semicolon`. And my ESLint parser highlights `as` with: `Parsing error: Unexpected token`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly nothing like that is possible in the [ECMA-262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-imports) specifications. They only lists these [possibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax):

```js
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export1 } from "module-name";
import { export1 as alias1 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export1 [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
var promise = import("module-name");
```

Best that you can do (only add a single line) is the following:

```js
import { cat, dog } from './animals';
const housePets = { cat, dog };
```

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on using housePets in other modules then also export housePets as a part of animals.js

**animals.js**

```
import cat from './cat';
import dog from './dog';
import emu from './emu';
import pig from './pig';
import cow from './cow';

const housePets = { cat, dog }

export { cat, dog, emu, pig, cow };
export { housePets };
```

**my-module.js**

```
import { cat, dog, housePets } from './animals';

console.log(cat);
console.log(dog);
console.log(housePets);
```

Answer (score 2):

As [@johannchopin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583669/johannchopin) mentioned in their answer, this is not possible as per the latest specs. However if you want import ALL the exports from a file in a single key name, you can try something like this -

`foo.js`

```js
const a = '123';
const b = 123;

export default { a, b };
```

`bar.js`

```js
import KeyName from './temp';

console.log(KeyName.a, KeyName.b);
```